# How can I restore my Windows certificate cache so I only have those from trusted CAs?

Tags: certificates, windows

All this talk about Superfish and other adware crap has made me healthily paranoid that a wrong certificate can enter my certificate cache at any time. I have no reason to assume that there is a malicious certificate in my cache right now, but you never know something might happen.

I'm looking for a way to restore my certificate cache to the default settings (so only those CAs that actually are trusted and are known to not be compromised are in there) in case I would need to do this one day. I am looking for an automated method that's in default Windows 7 and 8 and 8.1.

Is there such a way?

Comment: I Agree with Ohnana, Nate look at the link provided by Ohnana, it has the answer you are seeking.

Comment: Depends on how you define "trusted". Are you really still comfortable allowing a big corporation like Microsoft to define who your system will and won't trust as a CA?

Comment: @Iszi NSA inc. amirite?

Comment: @CameronVerotti I checked that one, it is more or less what I'm looking for, but I was hoping for there to be an automated method that has less risk of basically breaking SSL if you mess it up. Also, search didn't turn that up, neither did the example questions in the suggestions or the sidebar.

Comment: @Lucas'Paul'Kauffman Well yeah, doesn't everyone trust NSAInc?

Comment: @Iszi If you don't trust "a big corporation like Microsoft", then you shouldn't be using Windows in the first place.

Comment: @Iszi I guarantee you that if Microsoft would EVER allow a malicious CA willingly and knowingly into their certificate store, you're going to have litigation that will make the browser monopoly lawsuits from the past 16 years look like parking tickets (and yes, that's intentional hyperbole).

Comment: @NateKerkhofs "Malicious", in this context, is pretty subjective. Particularly concerning the fact that distribution of their products crosses practically every national border in existence.